# How to merge two different files and save in to a new file in a linux shell program

Tags: linux

I just want you to help me to write a shell script in linux programming. 
I want to merge two different files and save in to a new file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following example:

```
cat file1 > outputfile
cat file2 >> outputfile
```

Comment: I d suggest invoking it in one command.
$ cat file1 file2 > outputfile